# ASP.Net Menu(Items) running insecure

Tags: asp.net, security

I have a site which utilizes ASP.Net Menus inside a Master Page. When I run the page, I am told that it is displaying mixed content. The rendered code for the page contains the following lines:

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/4.0/2/WebForms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/4.0/2/MenuStandards.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is causing problems with Chrome in particular, as it is very touchy when it comes to running mixed content. The Ajax library that the site is built upon is hosted locally. I do not know where this reference is coming from, or how to get it to reference a secure version of the libraries.

I'm not sure exactly what you might need to see of my code to help troubleshoot, so I'll leave it off for now.

Comment: The scripts are loaded from Micrsoft's CDN. 

Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949504/scriptmanager-enablecdn-does-not-work-on-ssl

Comment: Thanks so much. This saved a bunch of time. If you add this as an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per gbs's comment (via his [link to the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949504/scriptmanager-enablecdn-does-not-work-on-ssl)), .NET 4.0 CDN references are not correct and needed to be manually overridden.