# HTTPS security is compromised by ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework

Tags: asp.net, ajax, iis, mixed-content

I have a ScriptManager in my aspx ASP.NET web page.

If I use the following

```
<asp:ScriptManager EnablePartialRendering="true" AsyncPostBackTimeOut="300"
        ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
```

I see the following errors in the browser

> Uncaught Error: ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: Sys is not defined

when I add `EnableCdn="true"` then I get a warning about the mixed content that reads

> HTTPS security is compromised by http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.6/1/WebForms.js ... and by http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.6/1/MicrosoftAjax.debug.js

Of course if I force loading, it eventually works, but this is very far from ideal.

I also don't understand how the issue has arisen in a porting from Windows Server 2012 to Windows Server 2016 with respective versions of IIS 8 and 10. Apparently, in the original server, the same code works fine - even without `EnableCdn="true"` - and all those requests seem to be managed in https as expected.

### After the accepted solution

Almost all went well.
What I've done is adding the following lines inside the `Global.asax.cs`:

```
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //....
        var defAjaxForms = new ScriptResourceDefinition();
        defAjaxForms.CdnPath = "https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.6/1/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.debug.js";
        defAjaxForms.CdnDebugPath = "https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.6/1/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.debug.js";
        defAjaxForms.CdnSupportsSecureConnection = true;
        defAjaxForms.Path = "~/Scripts/WebForms/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.debug.js";//local resource
        defAjaxForms.DebugPath = "~/Scripts/WebForms/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.debug.js";
        ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js", defAjaxForms);
        var defAjax = new ScriptResourceDefinition();
        defAjax.CdnPath = "https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.6/1/MicrosoftAjax.js";
        defAjax.CdnDebugPath = "https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.6/1/MicrosoftAjax.js";
        defAjax.CdnSupportsSecureConnection = true;
        defAjax.Path = "~/Scripts/WebForms/MicrosoftAjax.js";//local resource
        defAjax.DebugPath = "~/Scripts/WebForms/MicrosoftAjax.js";
        defAjax.LoadSuccessExpression = "window.Sys && Sys._Application && Sys.Observer";
        ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("MicrosoftAjax.js", defAjax);
        var defForms = new ScriptResourceDefinition();
        defForms.CdnPath = "https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.6/1/WebForms.js";
        defForms.CdnDebugPath = "https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.6/1/WebForms.js";
        defForms.CdnSupportsSecureConnection = true;
        defForms.Path = "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js";
        defForms.DebugPath = "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js";
        defForms.LoadSuccessExpression = "window.Sys && Sys._Application && Sys.Observer";
        ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("WebForms.js", defForms);
    }
```

The only thing that is still KO is the `WebForms.js`: I'm still getting

> ... was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script
>   'http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.6/1/WebForms.js'. This request has
>   been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

### Final Solution

Finally I applied [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12105756/10794413) (notice that they define `ResourceName` and `ResourceAssembly` instead of `Path` and `DebugPath`) **with all `http://` replaced by `https://`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure `ScriptManager` mapping in Code Behind. Something like this. `Page_PreRender` is good place for it.

```
Dim def As New ScriptResourceDefinition()
def.CdnPath = "https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js"
def.CdnDebugPath = "https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js"
def.CdnSupportsSecureConnection = True
def.Path = "~/js/lib/MicrosoftAjax.js" ''//local resource
def.DebugPath = "~/js/lib/MicrosoftAjax.js"
def.LoadSuccessExpression = "window.Sys && Sys._Application && Sys.Observer"
ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("MicrosoftAjax.js", def)
```

Comment: Will test this tomorrow morning, but it really looks what I was looking for. I have C# btw. Will let you know if any issues arise, thanks

Comment: I hope it is not big problem to translate to C#

Comment: You saved my life)) Спасибо!

Comment: I've a little follow-up question (see my edit): if you can fix it, you are definitely a guru! Thanks anyway, your answer is already enough.